# Does the "si passivante" come from the Latin passive case?

Tags: verbs, latin, infinitive, passive

Does the *si passivante* come from the Latin passive?

Comment: I would say, not formally: the Latin passive has a very different form, with special passive verb endings containing R. Functionally, I suspect it may have been the replacement of the Latin passive.

Answer (score 2):

There is a well-attested grammaticalisation path going:

> Relexive > middle > anticausative > passive > impersonal

This means that, in the contest of grammaticalisation, there are many occurrences of reflexive constructions turning into passives. Grammaticalisation itself is a very broad topic, but it probably suffices to say that it's a form of linguistic change making words or constructions more "functional" at each successive step; a simple example would be Latin *MICA* 'breadcrumb' > It. *mica*, a negation adverb void of any lexical meaning and thus purely functional. In the case of the *si*-passive, we can hypothesise a similar line of development starting with the Latin reflexive.

You may consult [this paper](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/54896881/FLH_Sanso_2011-libre.pdf?1509665353=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DGrammaticalization_paths_and_prototype_e.pdf&Expires=1686732677&Signature=gjy4tBIc3-j9PpSI6H3Fgl1DF-OsCkajr5PJGE3UBMEdOOIs8TTppLqTDjMEoARhkBKdIzDmYwtswf%7ES80ft9q3gh96YRItpqNyhZibrl%7Ehoa4bt8q7pAfUavzyMdRmGpuIKQwd4aayGvQ5k1PWPbKGRNHrAsZ4S7ugNHJ0RKFZp-IVIPDHaLqHysq8WxFw3seNPxVLfj5DWCkX98jcQJwFE0wzIR1dmN%7EATPlYofLXxEwP7TwqISUjzy49E29SBeLyn8lGri2blaTaQQtRmg9CumVjes-in8H27ypI6EVUjoHEJzxtKMpT99dLdp3kdJizoDKX3JzvE1EheCF-Bog__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA) (the link to the PDF file seems to not be working for some people, so [here](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/flih.2011.008/html) is the link to the article on the publisher's site) for more info.

Comment: The paper seem to be private and not accessible?

Comment: I am not sure why, it's a direct link to a PDF hosted on academia.edu. I have edited the answer to add another link.